# Export all data to Excel using GridView with paging enabled..in asp.net with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to export data to Excel. And I have GridView with paging enabled. When I download data using HtmlTextWriter it give download only to visible record in GridView. Can we download all the record in single excel file? And also downloaded-data should be with the same sorted state as sorted in GridView?

**Client Source code**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDetailFleet" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
        AllowPaging="false" AllowSorting="True"  AutoGenerateColumns="true"
        DataKeyNames="OracleId" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None"    >
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>
```

**Here is Server Side**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
public partial class FleetReportWithoutVehicle : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            btnFleetReportWithoutVehicle.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnFleetReportWithoutVehicle.Visible = true;
    }

    protected void btnExportSalary_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "AttendanceFollowUpReport.xls"));
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        gvDetailFleet.AllowPaging = false;
        gvDetailFleet.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "");
        for (int i = 0; i < gvDetailFleet.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            gvDetailFleet.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Style.Add("background-color", "");
        }
        gvDetailFleet.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }

    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you can do it but needs to get data again from the database or disable the gridview pagind and refresh Grid. I'ts better to make another method getting the data from the database and then build the excel.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to do like this

```
    GridView gv = new GridView();
      gv.DataSource = sourceList; //Your datasource from database
                gv.DataBind();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Preferred_Funds-" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".xls");
                Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
                Response.Charset = "";
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                gv.RenderControl(htw);
                Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
```

Comment: i already tried this and works perfectly in chrome but not in IE 11

Answer (score -1):

//try this code inside the button

```
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ExportData1.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
    StringWriter StringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter HtmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(StringWriter);

    //batigol
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.DataSource = Session["uu"];
    GridView1.DataBind();
    //

    GridView1.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter);
    Response.Write(StringWriter.ToString());
    Response.End();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Just a suggestion, consider adding an explanation to your answer. 'Code only answers' are frowned upon around here.